# Applying corrections to a subsampled copy of a dataframe back to the original dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series, timestamp

I'm a Pandas newbie, so please bear with me.

Overview:  I started with a free-form text file created by a data harvesting script that remotely accessed dozens of different kinds of devices, and multiple instances of each.  I used OpenRefine (*a truly wonderful tool*) to munge that into a CSV that was then input to dataframe `df` using Pandas in a JupyterLab notebook.

My first inspection of the data showed the `'Timestamp'` column was not monotonic.  I accessed individual data sources as follows, in this case for the `'T-meter'` data source. (*The technique was taken from a search result - I don't really understand it, but it worked.*)

```
cond = df['Source']=='T-meter'
rows = df.loc[cond, :]
df_tmeter = pd.DataFrame(columns=df.columns)
df_tmeter = df_tmeter.append(rows, ignore_index=True)
```

then checked each as follows:

```
df_tmeter['Timestamp'].is_monotonic
```

Fortunately, the problem was easy to identify and fix: Some sensors were resetting, then sending bad (but still monotonic) timestamps until their clocks were updated.  I wrote the function `healing()` to cleanly patch such errors, and it worked a treat:

```
df_tmeter['healed'] = df_tmeter['Timestamp'].apply(healing)
```

Now for my questions:

1. How do I get the `'healed'` values back into the original `df['Timestamp']` column for only the `'T-meter'` items in `df['Source']`?
2. Given the function `healing()`, is there a clean way to do this directly on `df`?

Thanks!

Edit: I first thought I should be using 'views' into `df`, but other operations on the data would either generate errors, or silently turn the views into copies.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a wrapper function `heal_row()` for `healing()`:

```
def heal_row( row ):
    if row['Source'] == 'T-meter':   # Redundant check, but safe!
        row['Timestamp'] = healing(row['Timestamp'])
    return row
```

then did the following:

```
df = df.apply(lambda row: row if row['Source'] != 'T-meter' else heal_row(row), axis=1)
```

This ordering is important, since `healing()` is stateful based on the prior row(s), and thus can't be the default operation.